# Problem with adding an event to the combo

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, extjs

I have a combobox:

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="cbGroup" runat="server" Width="150" 
        OnItemSelected="cbGroup_ItemSelected">
    </ext:ComboBox>
```

and a method:

```
    protected void cbGroup_ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FilterItemSelected(this, new EventArgs());
    }
```

when the item in the combobox is changed the method isnt triggered.

 what am i missing?

Comment: This isn't a default asp control. Please specify where you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `AutoPostBack="true"` on the control.

Comment: Either he's missing the correct event, or he's forgetting to set `AutoPostBack` to `true`; my guess is that it's the latter, since he's using some component framework, and the provided control may have the `OnItemSelected` event.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I know about the ASP.NET `DropDownList` control, I would say to look for an `AutoPostBack` property on the `ComboBox` and set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what component framework you're using, but the `asp:DropDownList` has the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event which will be triggered when an item is selected, with the assumption that `AutoPostBack` is set to `true`:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="cbGroup" runat="server" Width="150" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbGroup_ItemSelected"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**Update**: As I mentioned in my comment to Philip Smith's answer, I think the problem is that you don't set `AutoPostBack` to `true`; without this setting, the control won't trigger the event on the server-side, since `AutoPostBack` is standard set to `false`